# Three-way clustered robust standard errors in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, t-test, clustered-standard-errors

Suppose I have the following data:

```
loan_id    borrower_id    loan_amount     lender_id     var     time

 xxxx      xxxx            xxxx            xxxx         xxxx    20xx
```

Suppose that one borrower can have multiple lenders.

If I want to run the following regression:

loan_amount = var + \epsilon

Do I need to cluster by borrower_id, loan_id as well as time? Because a lender/borrower's characteristic might be correlated with the loan amount, and the characteristics might also be correlated through time. If so, am I looking at a three-way clustered robust standard error here?

Do you think the [multiway clustered robust standard error](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multiwayvcov/multiwayvcov.pdf) in R will work in this case? For example:

```
vcov <- cluster.vcov(model, cbind(borrower_id, lender_id, petersen$year))
```

and then use `coeftest(m1, vcov)` to get the clustered robust standard errors.

Do you think this makes sense?

Comment: What is your variable "var" about ?

Comment: It could be age, for instance. It could be other things too.